# Loop in ModelBuilder for compositing bands of multiple Images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, loop, iteration, composite

I'm attempting to automate the "Composite Bands" tool somehow in ModelBuilder, but haven't been able to figure out an effective method.
I have landsat 7 data that is separated into folders and each holds 7 bands (tif).  Basically I want to generate a model or script that composites all bands in the raster output for each location, and then saves the result in a output folder.
I've prepared a ModelBuilder that take each band and save it in its correspondent folder. However, the input raster just read 1 band, not all 6 bands. Any Solutions, maybe Python?
 [image: Model Builder]

[image: Composite Bands which just i raster uploaded :(]

Comment: Hi I am trying to replicate the same model at my end.
However, not able to do so. Is it possible to share the toolbox?
I am just wondering how that Output Path has come at the end which is linked to Composite Bands

Comment: HI @Neha... sorry for the late response. The Output Path is called %value% inside the Output Raster. I have some other toolbox to shared if needed. Let me know. Not sure if we can mention email contact by here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you are open to a Python solution, which is good because automating this process with Python is much easier and more flexible than a ModelBuilder approach.

First, import the necessary modules

```
import arcpy, os
```

Define the workspace that contains all of the folders with the Landsat imagery

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\imagery'
```

Specify where you would like the output to go

```
outws = r'C:\temp'
```

List all of the workspaces in the previously defined workspace

```
folders = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
```

Iterate through this list of workspaces and create a new list within each iteration of unstacked raster bands e.g. `['LC80260272014159LGN00_B1', 'LC80260272014159LGN00_B2',...]`

```
for folder in folders:
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
    name = os.path.join(outws, rasters[1].split("_")[0] + ".tif")
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasters, name)
```

Landsat files follows this form: `LC80260272014159LGN00_B1.tif`, so we need to strip off anything after the "_" and use the first basename as the output name.  You can do this with various slicing methods and string manipulation in Python.

```
name = os.path.join(outws, rasters[1].split("_")[0] + ".tif")
```

---

The complete script:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\imagery'
outws = r'C:\temp'

# list all folders in a directory

folders = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

for folder in folders:
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
    name = os.path.join(outws, rasters[1].split("_")[0] + ".tif")
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasters, name)

print "Processing complete"
```

Answer (score 3):

Create two models. One main and one sub. In the sub model, iterate through a folder to pick up the individual bands. Add [Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_using_Model_Only_tools_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001m000000/GUID-9F197B15-27F6-46EA-BAC5-7A722C5A3C4E/) at the end of the model. Refer to the [tool documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_using_Model_Only_tools_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001m000000/GUID-9F197B15-27F6-46EA-BAC5-7A722C5A3C4E/) for usage info. In the main model, call the sub model and pass the output from collect values to the composite bands tool.

Comment: Thanks @Nxau, I worked in the sub model and I can do the Composite Bands for one folder, however It cannot loop inside each folder. I realized I could also use "Iterate Folder" to repeat the SubModel on each folder, It does the first one but I got an error for next ones.

Check images of [Model](http://i.stack.imgur.com/su2PX.png) and the [SubModel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lUAjl.png)

Comment: To loop through subfolders, activate the **recursive** option in the [iterator tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/ESRI_SECTION1_2972801CD03B4BD49859ABB24FE01DB4/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The model is ready: It takes every Band from the main folder and sub folders to do a "Composite Bands". The result is saved in an "Ouput Path". A "Calculate Value" was used to just rename the result with the desirable part of the original name, avoiding, for instance, the double ".tif.tif". The [SubModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUAjl.png)  didn't change :)

[image: FinalModel]
[image: SubModel]