# NameError: name '**' not defined in ModelBuilder Calculate Value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-000539, calculate-values, nameerror

This question follows up on Crianopa's answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107687/126329 - I am attempting to do just this, but my model fails at the Calculate value stage. Using the expression from Crianopa "%value%"[0:6] I still get error message:

```
File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: LT05_L1GS_099072_20050106_20161127_01_T2_sr_band7 
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'LT05_L1GS_099072_20050106_20161127_01_T2_sr_band7' is not defined
```

Would anyone know where I am going wrong? I'm in 10.4.1.

I'm not familiar with python so I seek a ModelBuilder solution.

Comment: Yes, definitely using double-quotes. I have also ensured I have no spaces, only underscore in the file path, but no luck. I tried to calculate the value of Expression: Name (rather than Expression: Value) and this work, but the composite still fails later on.

Comment: The 'Calculate Values' operation also fails even without the code block input, so perhaps the issue is earlier on in my model.

Comment: Initially I put "%value%"[0:6] in the code block in the Calculate Values tool (not knowing where else to be able to add this expression) but the operation fails both with and without.

Comment: The code block should be empty.  `"%value%"[0:6]` should be in the 'Expression' field.

Comment: Of course, that works! Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97755/discussion-between-goanna-and-son-of-a-beach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, in the Calculate Value tool...

- The 'Code Block' field should be **empty**
- The 'Expression' field should be:  `"%value%"[0:6]`

(The expression should include the quotation marks.)

**Explanation:**

The 'Expression' is a simple one-liner Python expression that returns the result.

The 'Code Block' is an optional more complex Python script that will be run before the 'Expression' is evaluated.  The 'Expression' can then reference functions/variables created in the 'Code Block' if required.

In this case, the result can be evaluated in a simple one-line Python expression, and therefore no preceding code is required.